# Formula for $a_n$ where $a_n = n(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Formula for $a_n$ if $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$ and n greater than equal to 2

$a_n = n \times (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$.

Attempt: $ a_2 =6, a_3=24, a_4=120, a_5=720 , a_6 = 5040 $ It so looks like $a_n= (n+1)!$

I tried to open $n \times (n-1 \times (a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}) + a_{n-2})$.
Unable to get formula in factorial terms.

Comment: Hint: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: Using induction seems like cheating. I was thinking more in terms of generating functions, once unable to do directly by splitting.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that all you know about the sequence $a_n$ is an inductive definition, so you have to use induction to prove anything about it.  The use of induction might be implicit, but it's there somewhere. (If you wrote down all the formal details of a proof using generating functions, you'd have to use induction; if your proof uses $"\ldots"$ anywhere, a formal proof would use induction; etc.)

Comment: Wow! thanks, didn't know that. Always thought generating functions was the superior way to do recurrence relations.

Comment: Generating functions are fine, and they can be a great way to discover and organize a proof.  But fundamentally they aren't an alternative to induction; they're really a way to handle the bookkeeping of an induction automatically (and also to connect things with concepts of analysis, which can be useful).  So I certainly don't mean to discourage the use of generating functions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've noticed the pattern, it can be proved using induction on $n$:

For the base case, $a_0=1!$, $a_1=2!$.

For the induction step, if $n>1$ and $a_k=(k+1)!$ for $0\leq k\leq n-1$, then
$$ a_n=n(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})=n(n!+(n-1)!)=n(n-1)!(n+1)=(n+1)!$$

Comment: I was thinking in terms of generating functions. For me multiplying by $x^n$ both sides to get g.f seems to not work. Any way I can do this using generating functions. I am trying to learn g.f

Comment: Maybe try an exponential generating function instead? I think induction is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to solve this using generating functions and solving
ordinary differential equations. The use of ordinary generating
functions is more complicated due to convergence failure, but
exponential generating functions work in this case.

Suppose $\,a_n\,$ is a sequence of numbers. Then $\,y =E[a_n] := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n/n!\,$ is its exponential generating function. The two properties we need are $\, E[na_n] = xy'\,$ and $\,E[a_{n+1}] = y'.\,$ The recursion is $\,a_n = n \times (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}).\,$

We modify the recursion to be $\,a_{n+2} = (n+2)(a_{n+1} + a_n).\,$ Now $E[a_{n+2}] = y'',\,$
$\,E[a_{n+1}+a_n] = (y+y').\,$ The recursion becomes
$$ y'' = 2(y+y') + x(y+y')' = 2y + (x+2)y' + xy''. $$
Solving this differential equation with the initial conditions $\,y(0) = 1,\, y'(0) = 2\,$ gives the solution $\, y(x) = 1/(1-x)^2.\,$ Now $\, y = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n $ and thus $\,y = E[(n+1)n!]\,$ or simply $\,a_n = (n+1)!.$